# What typefaces were used in the Government’s Brexit leaflet of 2016?

Tags: typography

Can anyone tell me what typefaces are used here?

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Helvetica Neue, set in various weights.